# Centering Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sticky header on my page and I've been trying to center the content, but have been unsuccessful.

I have tried using offsets, using margin, and a few other things, but I just can't get it to move.

I don't want the actual text to be centered, **so text-align:center won't work**. I just want to center the entire content if that makes sense. and help would be appreciated!

My HTML looks like this

```
<div class="container">
        <header class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="sticky-header">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Customer Name: </label>
                            <label>Person!! </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Address: </label>
                            <label>101 Main Street </label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Email:</label>
                            <label>something@email.com </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">City, State:</label>
                            <label>Tavierner, FL </label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Phone:</label>
                            <label>555-555-5555 </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Club Code:</label>
                            <label>456 </label>
                            <label class="bold">Associate#:</label>
                            <label>45 </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
</div>
```

and my css looks like this

```
.header-wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    height: 0;
}

.sticky-header {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    position: static;
    top: -100px;
    padding: 10px;
    //text-align: center;
}

.sticky-header.sticky {
    background: #f9f8f0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sticky-header .form-group, .sticky-header label, #cts-ers .form-group{
    margin:0;
}
```

https://www.bootply.com/edHiY15iJy

Comment: Is this what you want ?  https://www.bootply.com/KSZY1QM9Mq

Comment: no, I want to center the header content....not the page content

Comment: An easy way of centring the content in your case is simple adding a `text-align: center` to your `sticky-header` selector

Comment: @Teknotica, but that centers the text. I need to the text to be left aligned so the titles do not have jagged edges.

Comment: Is this what you want https://www.bootply.com/z3icKH1iSD

Comment: @zazvorniki Have you checked last bootply I made  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you should add another `div` inside your `col-md-4`  with `inline-block` and `text-align:left` before that we center text inside yours columns.

I've adjusted your code:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <header class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="sticky-header">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                        <div class="helper">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="bold">Customer Name: </label>
                              <label>Person!! </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="bold">Address: </label>
                              <label>101 Main Street </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                      <div class="helper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Email:</label>
                            <label>something@email.com </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">City, State:</label>
                            <label>Tavierner, FL </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                      <div class="helper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Phone:</label>
                            <label>555-555-5555 </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="bold">Club Code:</label>
                            <label>456 </label>
                            <label class="bold">Associate#:</label>
                            <label>45 </label>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
  <section>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>
    <p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p><p>this</p>

  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    height: 0;
}

.sticky-header {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    position: static;
    top: -100px;
    padding: 10px;
    //text-align: center;
}

.sticky-header.sticky {
    background: #f9f8f0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sticky-header .form-group, .sticky-header label, #cts-ers .form-group{
    margin:0;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Also bootply with working solution https://www.bootply.com/z3icKH1iSD

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you want the content within `.sticky-header` to take up less of the total width. The easiest way to achieve this would be, as you surmised in your initial post, through the use of offsets.

Change the columns of your `.sticky-header` to use:

`<div class="col-md-3">`

And for the first column add `col-md-offset-2`.